# Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. MySQL Asp.Net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm receiving that error when I tried to insert data from a txt file into a mysql table. I tried with the whole list, with just 1 item, with csv, even removing the "" and creating a new table with just one field, but the problem continue happening after 30 seconds. In my txt have a list of numbers that I need to insert in 1 field of the table, eventhough the table has three different fields. Thank you in advance.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "text/plain")
            {

                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File, "+filename+" uploaded!";
                string dir = Server.MapPath("~/") + filename;
                string strcon = "SERVER = 000.000.000.00; " + "DATABASE=fakedb;" + "UID=fakeid;" +"PASSWORD=fakepass;";
                Response.Write(dir);
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strcon);
               con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + filename + "' INTO TABLE Cuenta_Test  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\r'", con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            else
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only txt files are accepted!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems your `MySqlCommand` command text is incorrect. It should be like this (note that you need to use double backslash `\\` instead of single backslash `\` so that C# don't treat the line terminator as escape sequences, it used for MySQL command string):

```cs
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + filename + "' INTO TABLE Cuenta_Test LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n\\r'", con);
```

Or use command text with `string.Format` & literal string like this:

```cs
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(string.Format(@"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{0}' INTO TABLE Cuenta_Test LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\r'", filename), con);
```

NB: You can also use `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` as fields separator when reading CSV file & save its contents to database.

Other suggestions you can do to ensure successful load data command:

1) Try running the same command in MySQL Workbench. Check against incorrect data type errors.

2) Increase command timeout using `CommandTimeout` property:

```cs
cmd.CommandTimeout = 120; // 2 minutes (example)
```

3) Normalize line endings of the text file before writing to database. `\n\r` escapes are different from `\r\n` (utilizing `Replace`, possibly using escape sequence regex).